# what does frame mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am reading the book "maintainable javascript".   in the book, the author talks about the frame, need help to understand what that means.

> Passing arrays back and forth **between frames** was one of the original **cross-frame issues**
>   in JavaScript. Developers quickly discovered that instanceof Array didn’t always produce
>   appropriate results in these cases. As mentioned previously, **each frame** has its
>   own Array constructor, so an instance from one **frame** isn’t recognized in another.
>   Douglas Crockford first recommended performing some duck typing, testing for the
>   presence of the sort() method:

```
// Duck typing arrays
function isArray(value) {
  return typeof value.sort === "function";
}
```

Comment: It relates (I think) to framesets. Not really applicable in today's web.

Comment: Frames. You know, HTML frames.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is referring to the [HTML `<frame>` element](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Elements/frame), or [the modern `<iframe>`](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Elements/iframe)

The point is that between frames, `Array` gets created separately and you can't do an `instanceof` comparison between an array created in one frame (possibly the main document) and an array created in the `<iframe>`'s code.